# Prevent to open appstorelink from UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I´ve a small app with a `UIWebView` for web surfing in it. On some pages opens the Appstore for promotional purposes (that is annoying). How can i prevent that? Is there a special method? or just fake the `browserid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/
here is the complete reference for link formation of the appstore, itunes.

from above reference link, `apple.com` is common for all kind of links.

So we can create regex or simply search string "apple.com" from url and avoid to load in webview.

If you wanna,use without regex following code may be help you :

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL *currentURL = request.URL;
  NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

  NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"apple.com"]; 
  if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
    return YES;
  else
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This will prevent loading `apple.com` or `developer.apple.com` websites as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to detect what URLs are getting loaded in the webview. App store URLs usually contain `itunes.apple.com` or `phobos.apple.com`.

When you encounter such urls are clicked, you can return `NO` from the web view delegate method to stop loading the url.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following UIWebView Delegate method for this :

```
 -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL *currentURL = request.URL;
  NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

  NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"https://itunes.apple.com"]; // Change URL if other than this.
  if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
    return YES;
  else
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I guess there are not only itunes.apple.com domain, searching algorithm might be extended (probably regular expressions) f.e also phobos.apple.com

Comment: Yes...if you want ,more than one links to be blocked .this can be changed as per requirement